# How can I prevent form submit action to be triggered?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my form where i have action event when I click on button.

```
<form id="prefForm4" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="masters"
    action="/Preferences/Preferences/RISSave">
</form>
```

I have two button which I will display them depending on some condition say when button1 is displayed it will perform the form action and when button2 is displayed it will trigger javascript function which perform the different action and it should not trigger form action, but I my case both methods are triggering.

```
<input id="button1" name="Save" class="button" type="submit" value="<%="Save".Localize()%>"/>

<input id="button2" name="Save" class="button" type="submit" value="<%="Save".Localize()%>"
                        onclick="saveData();" />
```

JavaScript below

```
function saveData() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Preferences/Preferences/saveData",
            type: "POST",
            data: items,
            success: function (reponse) {
                return true;
            },
            error: function (reponse) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault(); //this prevents default action

    //whatever else you want to do

    $('form').submit()
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Change your second button type from `submit` to `button` This will prevent the submission of the form.

```
<input id="button2" name="SavePACS" class="button" type="button" value="<%="SavePACS".Localize()%>"
                    onclick="saveData();" />
```

Comment: but i've still +1 that suggestion, since it's very relevant and simplest way "to not submit the form" by default. I like that.

Comment: @Mamun no worries :) will rm comment :)

Comment: @AndrewYmaz, you are right...otherwise I would have suggested `event.preventDefault()`......thanks

Answer (score 2):

Change where you call your function, instead of calling it inline create an event listener and then you prevent default actions

```
$('input[name=SavePACS]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    // then do your code here
});
```

Answer (score -1):

you should make the buttons **not** of type submit to prevent them from triggering the form submission.